# Develop Apple mobile application without submitting to Apple store

Tags: ios

I want to develop some mobile applications on iphone/ipad etc, but this is complete internal. I don't want to even go through for approval from apple store. Is there any way to do that? I saw Apple has some service for companies with 500+ people, but mine is definitely less than that.  Thanks.

Comment: If you pay for a developer licence, you can ad-hoc deploy to up to 100 devices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can enroll for [Enterprice distribution program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/gettingstarted/).Not an issue when company size is less than 500.Take account in developer.apple.com and you can distribute your apps using your own server.[diawi](http://www.diawi.com/) provide the distribution service for free